# pushed data is not refelcting in a table using angular

Tags: angularjs

the pushed data from the model is not reflecting in the first table. It is there in console. The fiddle link is attached with this please help me on this.
fiddle link   ----  http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/2649/

```
html=========

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <th>Attribute Name</th>
          <th>Attribute Value</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="newdetail in newDetails">
            <td>
              <p ng-model="detail">{{newdetail.attrName}} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p ng-model="detailValue">{{newdetail.userAttrValue}} </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Select Attribute</a>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
        <div class=" ngdialog-messsage modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <th>
                          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
                        </th>
                        <th>Attribute Name</th>
                        <th>Attribute Value</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                          <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="detail.Selected">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <p ng-model="detail">{{detail.attrName}}</p>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <select ng-model="detail.user_attr_value" ng-init="detail.user_attr_value=detail.attr_value_Ind.split(',')[0]" class="form-control full-width">
                              <option ng-repeat="option in detail .attr_value_Ind.split(',')" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Selected" ng-click="add();close('Cancel')">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger " ng-click="checkAll(details.length)" value="Clear">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

js===================


var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $element, ModalService) {
  $scope.newDetails = [{

    "attrName": "userType",

    "userAttrValue": "Customer",
    "userOrGroupId": "aaaazzz8522",

  }];

  $scope.add = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.details, function(detail) {
      if (detail.Selected == true) {

        $scope.newDetails.push({

          'attrName': detail.attrName,
          'attrName': detail.user_attr_value
        });


      $element.modal('hide');
      close($scope.newDetails, 500);
      console.log("loop", $scope.newDetails);
            }
    });

  };

  $scope.show = function() {
    ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: "Controller"
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {});
    });
  };


  //=================================================
  $scope.close = function(result) {
    close(result, 600);
  };
  $scope.details = [{

    "attrName": "region",
    "attrType": "USER",
    "attr_value_Ind": "CHN-N,CHN-S,CHN-C",
    "buId": "DEFAULT",

  }];
  var getAllSelected = function() {
    var selecteddetails = $scope.details.filter(function(detail) {
      return detail.Selected;
    });

    return selecteddetails.length === $scope.details.length;
  }

  var setAllSelected = function(value) {
    angular.forEach($scope.details, function(detail) {
      detail.Selected = value;
    });
  }

  $scope.allSelected = function(value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      return setAllSelected(value);
    } else {
      return getAllSelected();
    }
  }
  $scope.checkAll = function(Count) {
    angular.forEach($scope.details, function(details) {

      details.Selected = false;
    });

  };


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have updated your fiddle please check and review.http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/2652/

it's not pushing it's value because you have pass scope in your modal controller and set parent scope like this

```
ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: "Controller",
      scope:$scope <-- added here scope
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {});
    });
```

and add $parent to push your value like this

```
$scope.$parent.newDetails.push({       <-- added $parent here 
    'attrName': detail.attrName,
    'userAttrValue': detail.user_attr_value
 });
```